# By what modulo calculations with discrete logarithms are performed?

Tags: discrete-logarithm

For odd prime $p$, I have been given a group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ of all invertible elements from $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Basically, $\mathbb{Z}_p^* = \{1,2,\ldots , p-1 \}$. I also have $a$ and $b$, which are two generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. My question is, by what modulo calculations with the discrete logarithm are performed for $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$? Or in other words, does it hold:
$$ a^k \equiv b \pmod p$$
$$k \equiv \log_a b \pmod{p}$$
Or does it hold:
$$ a^k \equiv b \pmod{p-1}$$
$$k \equiv \log_a b \pmod{p-1}$$

And also, a followed up question: 
If $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, $a$ and $b$ are as described above, does it holds, that if $k=\log_a b$ then $k\in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$?

Comment: $\mod p$, This was intended to be an educative answer : [Discrete Logarithm: Given a p, what does it mean to find the discrete logarithm of x to base y?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298) if not clear, please indicate, Also see  [Does classifying an integer as a discrete log require it be part of a multiplicative group?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68851/18298)

Comment: So [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87014/show-how-an-efficient-algorithm-for-computing-discrete-logarithms-with-base-a-ca/87019?noredirect=1#comment190972_87019), where user @fgrieu♦ suggested that operations with discrete logarithm are performed by $\bmod{(p-1)}$ is wrong?

Comment: It is the power, see Euler's Theorem. You should take an introduction to abstract algebra course.

Comment: So, $a^k \equiv b \pmod p$, but $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$?

Comment: Yes and no. $a^{\varphi(k)} = 1 \bmod n$ where $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $\gcd(a,p)=1$. There is a representative of $k \in \varphi(n)$ that is $k' = k + t\cdot \varphi(n) $. Since $n$ is a prime than $\varphi(n) = n-1$. See a recent [RSA question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87020/18298) about Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the question's alternative hold.

For any $n>1$, and any $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$,
$$a^k \equiv b \pmod n\quad\iff\quad k \equiv \log_a b \pmod{\text{ord}_n(a)}$$

where $\text{ord}_n(a)$ is the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of $a$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_n^*$, that is the smallest $r\ge1$ with $a^r\equiv1\pmod n$.

The order of an element divides the order of the group, which is $\varphi(n)$ for group $\mathbb Z_n^*$, where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) function. Therefore
$$k\equiv\log_a b \pmod{\varphi(n)}\quad\implies\quad a^k \equiv b \pmod n$$

When $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_n^*$, which is testable as $a^{\varphi(n)/q}\not\equiv1\bmod p$ for every prime $q$ dividing $\varphi(n)$, we simply have
$$a^k \equiv b \pmod n\quad\iff\quad k \equiv \log_a b \pmod{\varphi(n)}$$

---

Restating this for prime $p$, and any $a$ with $a\not\equiv0\pmod p$,
$$k\equiv\log_a b \pmod{(p-1)}\quad\implies\quad a^k \equiv b \pmod p$$
and, for the lowest $r\ge1$ dividing $p-1$ such that $a^r\equiv1\pmod p$,
$$a^k \equiv b \pmod p\quad\iff\quad k \equiv \log_a b \pmod{r}$$

When $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_p^*$, which is testable as $a^{(p-1)/q}\not\equiv1\bmod p$ for every prime $q$ dividing $(p-1)$, we simply have
$$a^k \equiv b \pmod p\quad\iff\quad k \equiv \log_a b \pmod{(p-1)}$$

Comment: Good, another educative answer.